# renaming files in a folder by other file names in another folder with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rename, file-rename, folderbrowserdialog

i'm writing a programme and i guess the title explain it all .

and it did work but with one file only , problem is the program ignores the next claarving the first file - the success - is still his priority and he can't find it so it crashes

this is my code

```
          Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(TextBox2.Text)


    Dim info As New IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim imfo2 As New IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBox2.Text)
    For Each fi In imfo2.GetFiles


        For Each foo In info.GetFiles
            Dim namewithoutavi As String = foo.Name.Substring(0, foo.Name.Length - 4)
            Dim fixedname As String = namewithoutavi & ".srt"

            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(fi.FullName, fixedname)      


        Next

    Next



End Sub
```

can someone please tell me how to make it right ?
as you can see i'm a beginner and i'm really desperate for help  :)

Comment: Why are you renaming each `fi` file multiple times? That is what the inner foreach is doing. Which files do you want to rename?

Comment: i want to rename the      fi       , and i only used the inner foreach becuase the foreach allows me to retrieve the files and deal with " each " file and i want so replace each file name the outer foreach provides with each file name in the inner .. 
so is there any way i can retrieve the files and use their proprties without having to use 2 foreach'es :) 
and thank u

Comment: You're renaming fi.FillName to the first instance of foo. Then on the second instance of foo, fi.FileName doesn't exists anymore since it was renamed. Also, checked [System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: sorry i dont understand how can this help me